# I am creating 2 state svg powered animated icons but get error

Tags: javascript

I am creating 2 state svg powered animated icons i used icon transition generator website name nucleoapp i upload two svg icons they give me code when i include full code in html it worked perfectly but when i remove script tags and cut the javascript code and paste in my javascript file it give me this error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="512" width="512">
  <g class="nc-icon-wrapper js-transition-icon" data-effect="scale" data-event="click">
    <g class="js-transition-icon__state" style="">
      <path d="M368.5 240H272v-96.5c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16s-16 7.2-16 16V240h-96.5c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16 0 4.4 1.8 8.4 4.7 11.3 2.9 2.9 6.9 4.7 11.3 4.7H240v96.5c0 4.4 1.8 8.4 4.7 11.3 2.9 2.9 6.9 4.7 11.3 4.7 8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V272h96.5c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16s-7.2-16-16-16z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="js-transition-icon__state" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <path d="M368.5 240h-225c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16 0 4.4 1.8 8.4 4.7 11.3 2.9 2.9 6.9 4.7 11.3 4.7h225c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16s-7.2-16-16-16z"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
  <script>
    ! function() {
      "use strict";
      if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
        var a = null;
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(t, i) {
          var e = (new Date).getTime();
          a || (a = e);
          var s = Math.max(0, 16 - (e - a)),
            n = window.setTimeout(function() {
              t(e + s)
            }, s);
          return a = e + s, n
        }
      }

      function r(t, i, e, s) {
        return 1 & gt;
        (t /= s / 2) ? e / 2 * t * t * t * t + i: -e / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + i
      }

      function e(t) {
        return t ? [1, 0] : [0, 1]
      }

      function t(t) {
        this.element = t, this.svg = function t(i) {
          var e = i.parentNode;
          if ("svg" !== e.tagName) e = t(e);
          return e;
        }(this.element), this.getSize(), this.states = this.element.querySelectorAll(".js-transition-icon__state"), this.time = {
          start: null,
          total: 200
        }, this.status = {
          interacted: !1,
          animating: !1
        }, this.animation = {
          effect: this.element.getAttribute("data-effect"),
          event: this.element.getAttribute("data-event")
        }, this.init()
      }
      t.prototype.getSize = function() {
        var t = this.svg.getAttribute("viewBox");
        this.size = t ? {
          width: t.split(" ")[2],
          height: t.split(" ")[3]
        } : this.svg.getBoundingClientRect()
      }, t.prototype.init = function() {
        var t = this;
        this.svg.addEventListener(t.animation.event, function() {
          t.status.animating || (t.status.animating = !0, window.requestAnimationFrame(t.triggerAnimation.bind(t)))
        })
      }, t.prototype.triggerAnimation = function(t) {
        var i = this.getProgress(t);
        this.animateIcon(i), this.checkProgress(i)
      }, t.prototype.getProgress = function(t) {
        return this.time.start || (this.time.start = t), t - this.time.start
      }, t.prototype.checkProgress = function(t) {
        if (this.time.total & gt; t) window.requestAnimationFrame(this.triggerAnimation.bind(this));
        else {
          this.status = {
            interacted: !this.status.interacted,
            animating: !1
          }, this.time.start = null;
          var i = e(this.status.interacted);
          this.states[i[0]].removeAttribute("aria-hidden"), this.states[i[1]].setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true")
        }
      }, t.prototype.animateIcon = function(t) {
        if (t & gt; this.time.total) {
          t = this.time.total;
        }
        if (0 & gt; t) {
          t = 0;
        };
        var i = e(this.status.interacted);
        this.states[i[0]].style.display = t & gt;
        this.time.total / 2 ? "none" : "block", this.states[i[1]].style.display = t & gt;
        this.time.total / 2 ? "block" : "none", "scale" == this.animation.effect ? this.scaleIcon(t, i[0], i[1]) : this.rotateIcon(t, i[0], i[1])
      }, t.prototype.scaleIcon = function(t, i, e) {
        var s = r(Math.min(t, this.time.total / 2), 1, -.2, this.time.total / 2).toFixed(2),
          n = r(Math.max(t - this.time.total / 2, 0), .2, -.2, this.time.total / 2).toFixed(2);
        this.states[i].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.size.width * (1 - s) / 2 + " " + this.size.height * (1 - s) / 2 + ") scale(" + s + ")"), this.states[e].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.size.width * n / 2 + " " + this.size.height * n / 2 + ") scale(" + (1 - n) + ")")
      }, t.prototype.rotateIcon = function(t, i, e) {
        var s = r(t, 0, 180, this.time.total).toFixed(2);
        this.states[i].setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-" + s + " " + this.size.width / 2 + " " + this.size.height / 2 + ")"), this.states[e].setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + (180 - s) + " " + this.size.width / 2 + " " + this.size.height / 2 + ")")
      };
      var i = document.querySelectorAll(".js-transition-icon");
      if (i)
        for (var s = 0; i.length & gt; s; s++) new t(i[s])
    }();

  </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hard to tell you if you don't point the line that throws the etror. But as widely known, this error is about syntax error. You forgot closing some parenthesis, or placed the ; in wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Note that the text inside the `<svg>`'s script tag is HTML-escaped. You cannot directly copy-paste it.

(2) Look at things like

> `if (t & gt; this.time.total) {`

It must have been `t > this.time.total`, but it was escaped as `1 &gt; this.time.total`, and then some semantics-oblivious code prettifier added a space between `&` and `gt;`.

I think you now understand how to make the script work outside `<svg><script>`.